Stripe hcaptcha throwing 401
In my react-native app, I'm using stripe integration, and when I try to add a card to my UI the action sheet pops up and allows users to enter their card details all of a sudden I'm getting an error from POST https://api.hcaptcha.com/authenticate 401 (Unauthorized).
response {"pass":false,"error-codes":["pat-missing-auth"]} this is only happening on the web not on the native apps
then looked through the SO and found a similar issue. but none of the solutions worked. this integration worked well previously but I have upgraded my SDK after that I'm getting this issue. I also upgraded the all lib related stripes as well but in both version, this error exists
FYI: I'm not using hCaptcha directly it's using inside Stipe for fraud detection https://docs.stripe.com/disputes/prevention/advanced-fraud-detection?client=react all the payments are going through but this error occurred in console when ever I open the card modal
 "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^1.10.0" --> "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^2.7.0",
 "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.35.0", --->  "@stripe/stripe-js": "^3.3.0",
 "@stripe/stripe-react-native": "~0.15.0", --->  "@stripe/stripe-react-native": "~0.35.1",

here is how I'm getting my stripe loaded
import { loadStripe as loadStripeJs } from '@stripe/stripe-js/pure';

export const loadStripe = async (hotel: Hotel) => {
  const publicKey = __stripe_test_pk__;

  const stripeAccount = org.stripe?.accountId

  return loadStripeJs(publicKey, { stripeAccount });
};


Did you add a valid hcaptcha key somewhere in the config then?  Possibly related https://s-plugins.com/stripe-payments-hcaptcha-integration/

@NicoleZ is this a blocking error or just an warning message printed in your browser console? Can you manage to reproduce on the official quickstart sample preview  https://docs.stripe.com/payments/quickstart?client=react ?

@os4m37 it's not a warning. it's an error but it does not have any impact on stripe payment. I couldn't figure out why this is happening suddenly with `hcaptcha because there is no place for any hcaptcha specific token.

Have you had a chance to reproduce on the official quickstart I shared above ?

@os4m37 was stuck with work i will try reproduce it today and share it here

I found this question while experiencing the same issue (Stripe hcaptcha 401 error). In my case, the solution was to go to my Stripe dashboard and add my domain to the list of authorized payment method domains:
https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/payment_method_domains
If using Apple Pay, you also need to add the verification file to your domain per the instructions that Stripe will show you.
After adding the domain, the hcaptcha 401 issue disappeared.
Special thanks to @os4m37 for posting in a comment that the OP should try to reproduce the 401 issue using the official Stripe quickstart. I tried doing this myself per the suggestion after reading their comment, and that's what led me to discover the domain authorization issue that solved it.

Thank you - as an added note - I had added my domain with capitals in it and apparently stripe treats that as a separate domain, so I added it all lowercase and the error went away.  It was also the reason my Apple Pay wasn't working.
